# (T-SQL) Sum datetime value gaps based on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Need help writing a query which will sum up time values in date time fields based on another column. Let me explain:

Let's say I have a table **Table1** with 2 fields: **timeStamp** of DATETIME type and **player** VARCHAR. Let's say I input down a timestamp when playerA got the ball, after some time the playerB got the ball and I input his time, so eventualy I will have something like this:

```
+-------------------------+---------+
|        TimeLapse        | Player  |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 2017-07-03 10:37:14.740 | playerA |
| 2017-07-03 11:49:14.787 | playerB |
| 2017-07-03 11:53:59.157 | playerA |
| 2017-07-03 12:58:30.313 | playerA |
| 2017-07-03 12:58:34.000 | playerB |
| 2017-07-03 13:58:43.327 | playerA |
| 2017-07-04 19:48:39.817 | playerA |
| 2017-07-05 11:54:53.657 | playerA |
+-------------------------+---------+
```

What I want in the end is to count the time (let's say in minutes) when the playerA had the ball (**only when he had the ball**).
I'm a bit stuck. I have no problems getting all the times playerA had the ball, but then I somehow need to substract the time playerB had the ball.
So I need to sum:

```
time from
 | 2017-07-03 10:37:14.740 | playerA |
to
 | 2017-07-03 11:49:14.787 | playerB |
then from
 | 2017-07-03 11:53:59.157 | playerA |
to
 | 2017-07-03 12:58:30.313 | playerA |
and to
 | 2017-07-03 12:58:34.000 | playerB |
...
and so on
```

Can someone suggest a strategy, or show how it is done?
Thank you.

Comment: How does playerA pass the ball to himself? Surely that record shouldnt exist?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But that just stupid example on my part. I should have probably go with another example, but yes this record is possible. Let's say he has the ball, then dropped it then got it again! Time when ball is dropped not important.

Comment: so the gaps you're wanting to sum are gaps between player and self, and player and other.

Comment: Yes. You're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the difference of row numbers approach to identify the groups.  Then you can use aggregation and `lead()` to get the start and end times, as in the following:

```
select player, min(timelapse) as start_timelapse, 
       lead(max(timelapse)) over (order by max(timelapse)
                                 ) as next_timelapse
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (order by timelapse) as seqnum_t,
             row_number() over (partition by player order by timelapse) as seqnum_tp
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by (seqnum_t - seqnum_tp), player;
```

How this works is a bit tricky.  Run the subquery to figure out why the difference of the two row numbers identifies the groups you want.

For the time difference, you want to use the two columns returned.  It is unclear what units you want for that, but `datediff()` would be the typical method.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like what I need. I was thinking about **LAG()** myself, but had not come with a complete idea. The only thing I don't understand is `lag(max(timelapse)) over (partition by player, (seqnum_t - seqnum_tp) order by max(timelapse) as next_timelaps` Do I need to use datediff in place of (seqnum_t - seqnum_tp) to get difference with start_ and lagged_?

Comment: @JohnDoe . . . Ooops, that should be `lead()`, not `lag()`, because you want the next one.

Comment: Yes, yes) That I got. Still, the `LEAD` or `LAG` gives me NULL. I do not understand why. Subquery runs fine and I see rank numbers of seqnum_t and _tp. But with `over (partition by player, (seqnum_t - seqnum_tp)
                                  order by max(timelapse)` next_timelapse is NULL

Comment: @JohnDoe . . . For the `lead()` we don't want to partition by player or grp . . . we just want the next one.

Comment: Great! Thank You Gordon Linoff. Need to spend more time learning `LAG` and `LEAD`